# SSL Handshake issue on cloudera 5.9

Tags: java, ssl, https, salesforce, cloudera

I am trying to use sales force wave api library (https://github.com/springml/salesforce-wave-api) in cloudera cluster 5.9 to get data, I have to use proxy because from our cluster its the only way to communicate outside world.
So I made changes to the library to take proxy host and port to communicate below are the place where I made changes.

Change 1:-

```
config.setProxy("myenterpiseproxy server",port);
```

https://github.com/springml/salesforce-wave-api/blob/0ac76aeb2221d9e7038229fd352a8694e8cde7e9/src/main/java/com/springml/salesforce/wave/util/SFConfig.java#L101

Change 2:-

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("myenterpiseproxy server", port, "http");
```

https://github.com/springml/salesforce-wave-api/blob/0ac76aeb2221d9e7038229fd352a8694e8cde7e9/src/main/java/com/springml/salesforce/wave/util/HTTPHelper.java#L127

Change 3:-

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(timeout)
            .setConnectTimeout(timeout).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setProxy(proxy).build();
```

https://github.com/springml/salesforce-wave-api/blob/0ac76aeb2221d9e7038229fd352a8694e8cde7e9/src/main/java/com/springml/salesforce/wave/util/HTTPHelper.java#L129

I built an application to use salesforce wave api as dependency and I tried to execute the Jar I am getting SSL handshake issue.

I passed in javax.net.ssl.truststore,javax.net.ssl.keyStore,https.protocols of my cluster still having problems.

Did anyone had similar issue ? did anyone tried to use this library in cloudera cluster ?

Run Book:-

```
java -cp httpclient-4.5.jar:SFWaveApiTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.az.sfget.SFGetTest "username" "passwordwithtoken" "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35" "select id,OWNERID from someobject" "enterpiseproxyhost" "9400" "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts" "/opt/cloudera/security/jks/uscvlpcldra-keystore.jks"
```

Error:-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:388)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.execute(HTTPHelper.java:122)
    at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.get(HTTPHelper.java:88)
    at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.get(HTTPHelper.java:92)
    at com.springml.salesforce.wave.impl.ForceAPIImpl.query(ForceAPIImpl.java:120)
    at com.springml.salesforce.wave.impl.ForceAPIImpl.query(ForceAPIImpl.java:36)
    at com.az.sfget.SFGetTest.main(SFGetTest.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please post the solution if your problem was resolved.

Comment: @ziddarth I havent but some one has solved it I will try to get the answer